# How does dictionary setdefault method work?

Tags: python

I am doing the following in the python shell:

```
a = [0, 1]
b = [2, 4]
c = [2, 0]
d = [4, 3]

e = [a, b, c, d]
neighbour_list = {}
```

and i want to try the following:

```
neighbour_list.setdefault(x, [])
```

then

```
print(neighbour_list)
```

prints

```
{4: []}
```

I dont understand what it is doing. Why is x chosen by python to be 4?

Comment: What is `neighbour_list`? And what do you have in the variable `x`?

Comment: why do you have the variables  `a,b,c,d,e` and `abcd_list `  in your question when they are not used at all in your code and you have not provided `neighbour_list` and `x` which are the actual relevant  variables?

Comment: my bad abdc_list is actually neighbour_list and x is not defined i just randomly put it in the shell to see what action it would have

Comment: x is definitely defined somewhere or you will get an error.

Comment: restart your shell and try running your code again

Answer (score 3):

This will happen if `x` has been previously defined to be `4`. Python didn't "choose to define" this, you must have.

In the code you provided, you're not showing how `x` was defined, but it definitely has been defined, or else you'd get a `NameError`:

```
>>> abcd_list = {}
>>> abcd_list.setdefault(x, [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> x=4
>>> abcd_list.setdefault(x, [])
[]
>>> abcd_list
{4: []}
```

Comment: no because when i say print(x) it says x is not defined @Tim Pietzcker

Comment: @Hannah: Where exactly is the difference between your "x is not defined" and my "x is not defined" error?